# Arranging inputs within a form

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website but I have a problem arranging input items.

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

but it looks like this:
[image]

My HTML code:

```
    <div id="search">
      <form action="">
        <input class="search-area" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Search here">
        <input class="search-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="SEARCH">
      </form>
    </div>
```

My CSS code:

```
#search{
    width: 650px;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.search-area{
    width: 650px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;

}
.search-btn{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    color:#fff;
    background: brown;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Please help me to understand the problem.

Comment: The combined width of the search area and button exceeds that of the container, hence the line break. If you want to achieve the desired layout, position your button absolutely within the container.

Comment: Use bootstrap. You just need to change some styles.  So it will save a lot of time 
 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add position:relative to your main div, which is the #search.
Then add position:absolute to the button, and right:0 in order to align it to the right of the relative element.

```
#search{
position:relative;
}

.search-btn{
position:absolute;
right:0
}
```

Maybe you will also need a top positioning of the button. You can add top:5px for example to achieve that.

Cheers

Comment: Of course it does ;) I'm glad you can move on with you code.

Comment: @ahmedmohamady could you please select my answer as final? I am trying to collect some points here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To position the search-button above another element it has to be `position: absolute`.

Here you go:

```css
body {
  background: lightgreen;
}

#search {
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.search-area {
  width: 550px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.search-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div id="search">
  <form action="">
    <input class="search-area" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Search here">
    <input class="search-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="SEARCH">
  </form>
</div>
```